# Should I worry about GitHub using IP addresses that are described as having an unknown host?

Tags: ssh, dns, ip, git

Today, I got a message while doing a `git push`, saying

> Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '192.30.253.112' to the list of known hosts.

It seems as if it's consistent with what GitHub uses, based on [What IP addresses does GitHub use that I should whitelist?](https://help.github.com/articles/what-ip-addresses-does-github-use-that-i-should-whitelist/) though I haven't tried looking up how CIDR notation works.

However, if I try looking up 192.30.253.112 at http://ip-lookup.net/index.php , the "Host" information just has a literal question mark. It's only if I open up the "IP owner info (Whois)" section that I see it's associated with GitHub.

Is this unusual behaviour I should worry about from a security perspective?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, you should not be worried, but you should be checking [GitHub's server fingerprint](https://help.github.com/articles/what-are-github-s-ssh-key-fingerprints/) rather then relying on IP addresses.

With `git` command you do it only on first (ever) connection. If the public key (corresponding to the fingerprint) is in `known_hosts` file, subsequent connections to `github.com` cause only warning if the domain got resolved to a new IP address.
It is equivalent of using `ssh` command with `CheckHostIP=no` option.

You should be cautious (and check with a trusted source) if a new fingerprint was displayed on your screen for confirmation.

---

Regarding `ip-lookup.net` results:

`ip-lookup.net` figures out what DNS name is associated with an IP address using a reverse DNS.

In case of `192.30.253.112` it queries the address `112.253.30.192.in-addr.arpa` which does not have a corresponding forward DNS record.

It seems like a misconfiguration or not strictly enforced-one on GitHub side, however the verification mechanism would not be viable in this scenario.

In case of Git (SSH) client connecting to `github.com` domain, if you assumed a compromised DNS server redirecting to a rogue IP, the verification of the destination address using reverse DNS lookup would be susceptible to the same attack (compromised DNS server would confirm the address to belong to `github.com` owner with reverse DNS).

Regardless of IP ownership verification, checking the server fingerprint assures no server impersonation or MitM attack is taking place.